# Blank Page After SSL Re-Install with nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ssl, ubuntu-20.04

I seem to have hit a problem. I had a live website, and decided to change the domain name, this involved removing the old SSL and adding a new one in.

Server settings:
Ubuntu 20.4
Nginx(Latest version)
MariaDb
php-fpm
Wordpress

So the steps I taken to remove the ssl were the following:

cp -r /etc/letsencrypt/ /etc/letsencrypt.backup
certbot revoke --cert-path /etc/letsencypt/archive/healthwellnesssynergy.com/cert1.pem

certbot delete

sudo apt purge nginx nginx-common nginx-core

Then I re-installed Nginx, ran certbot installation, installed the ssl, restarted nginx, but when I go to my new domain, it is just a blank white page. I tried to debug it, but there is nothing in the logs.
When i enable WP debug, nothing happens. And wappalizer plugin does not even show Wordpress present in the list.

I am not really sure what I am missing, I checked all the statuses, and it is all running, mariadb and nginx are functioning as intended.

Are there any other steps I need to take when I switch SSL?

Here is my nginx config

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php;

    server_name hwscenter.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hwscenter.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hwscenter.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = hwscenter.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name hwscenter.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.. forgot to uncomment a line for the NginX Config.

## include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;